# Is there way to create a repeatable of hash of a sting that is guaranteed to work on any machine with version 4 of the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, hash, cryptography

I need to way of generating a hash to use as filename on Windows of constant length from a string. It doesn't need be particularly cryptographically secure. I was going to use MD5, fold it half and convert it to hex, but then I noticed that `MD5.Create()` can throw an `InvocationException`.

I read online that creation of the MD5 and other cryptography classes can fail on machines on which FIPS compliance is enforced. Is there way of generating a hash which is repeatable, guaranteed not to throw and has a reasonably low rate of collision?

Comment: Just take any other implementation of MD5 or something more decent like SHA256.

Comment: If you do not need cryptographic security then there are simple, fast non-crypto hashes, such as the [FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) hash.  One of them may suit your needs better.

Comment: Or you can use a code copy of an MD5 implementation. With a bit of luck you don't have to copy the entire crypto lib infrastructure with it. Document you don't use it for crypto purposes though, otherwise you can just wait for the trouble to happen. Beware that managed implementations will probably have a performance penalty (I'd guess about twice as slow compared to a C/C++ compiled version).

Comment: @Zergatul Although it seems it will hold up for now, even SHA-2 could throw such exceptions *in the future*. The SHA-3 competition did not happen for no reason. Maybe FIPS won't allow SHA-2 at a later date because of length extension attacks, who knows?